# Json.NET - how to serialize an external class with internal constructor?

Tags: c#, oop, serialization, json.net, private-constructor

I need to serialize a class which it's source code cannot be changed (take this as a fact), and it's from a different assembly. It has only one constructor

```
public class MyObject
{
    string _s;
    int _i;
    internal MyObject(string s, int i)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)` fails of course because of this. I wonder if there is a way to use Json.NET to serialize this class without having to adding code or even tags to it.

Comment: What is the error message you get when it fails? Reason I ask, shouldn't the `DeserializeObject` be throwing the exception if it's related to the constructor, as this is when it has to construct the object again.

Comment: Is the `MyObject` class sealed? Can you inherit it?

Comment: @MarioStoilov It's not sealed.

Comment: you could try inheriting the class and defining a parameterless constructor in the new class

Comment: @MarioStoilov you cannot do that in C#. The constructor is internal.

Comment: @shay__ I am pretty sure you can inherit classes in C# and I am also pretty sure you can define addition constructors as well as hide the previous ones. Have you tried it?

Comment: @MarioStoilov thanks for your comments. What I meant is - **you can't define a parameterless constructor in the inherited class**, since the base class does not expose it's parameterless ctor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a **parameterless constructor**, you should be able to do this by adding the following setting:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
};

var serializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonString, settings);
```

**Update after question edit:**

If you don't have **any** `public` constructors and you don't have a parameterless constructor, then I only know of 2 options:

1. Add the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to your `internal` constructor (which doesn't seem an option in your case as you cannot edit the class).
2. Create a proxy class with similar properties (not as elegant but no change to the class needed).

Comment: The proposed solution can't be used, because *source code cannot be changed (take this as a fact)* as was stated in a question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [custom JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

The solution would be something like

```
public class MyObjectProxy
{
    public string s { get; set; }
    public int i { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Create an instance of MyObjectProxy, copy values from the
        // instance of MyObject, write JSON from the MyObjectProxy.
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type type, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Deserialize MyObjectProxy, create an instance of MyObject,
        // copy properties from the deserialized MyObjectProxy.
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(MyObject).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proxy class with similar properties:

```
public sealed class TargetClass{
    public static readonly TargetClass tc = new TargetClass();
    public int Id;
    public string SomeName;
    private TargetClass(){
        this.Id=50;
        this.SomeName="My, What Bastardry";
    }
}
public class ProxyClass{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string SomeName {get; set;}
    public ProxyClass(){
    }
    public ProxyClass(int id, string somename){
        Id = id;
        SomeName = somename;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TargetClass tgt = TargetClass.tc;
        ProxyClass pc = new ProxyClass(tgt.Id,tgt.SomeName);
        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pc);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick and dirty example using Reflection and a proxy object, but you can use it in conjunction with the custom JsonConvertors mentioned by others: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OtOXSm